# How to set default values in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and fairly new to C# and I'm following along Head First C# 2nd Ed. p.218 (but a WPF version instead of a WinForms version). I have a `TextBox` on my form and I want to have a default string displayed when the form loads. I have two problems:

1. If I set the `Text` property in my XAML code,  the `TextChanged` event fires on form load and I get a `NullReferenceException`. Here's my XAML snippet:

   `<TextBox Name="cakeWritingText" Text="Happy Birthday" TextChanged="cakeWritingText_TextChanged" />`
2. If I set the value in my code instead (and remove the XAML `Text` property) like this: `cakeWritingText.Text = "Happy Birthday";`, I get this error:

> No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.

Here's the full event handler:

```
private void cakeWritingText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    birthdayParty.CakeWriting = cakeWritingText.Text;
    DisplayBirthdayPartyCost();
}
```

and the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dinnerParty = new DinnerParty(5, (bool)healthyCheckBox.IsChecked, (bool)fancyCheckBox.IsChecked);          
    DisplayDinnerCost();

    birthdayParty = new BirthdayParty(5, (bool)fancyBdayCheckBox.IsChecked, cakeWritingText.Text);
    numPeopleBdayUpDown.Value = 5;
    cakeWritingText.Text = "Happy Birthday";
    DisplayBirthdayPartyCost();
}
```

What's the best way to put a default string in a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to set a default, hard-coded value is in the XAML, so your first approach is correct. The issue arises in your event handler of the `TextChanged` event. This event will be fired inside of `InitializeComponent`, at which point your `birthdayParty` variable won't have been set, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

To overcome this, check in your event handler that your `birthdayParty` variable has been initialized. So your event handler will look like this:

```
private void cakeWritingText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (birthdayParty == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    birthdayParty.CakeWriting = cakeWritingText.Text;
    DisplayBirthdayPartyCost();
}
```

This will obviously result in you missing the first setting of the `CakeWriting` property, so you will need to get this value inside your constructor, after initializing the variable.

However, if you want the `CakeWriting` property to always hold the value inside your `TextBox`, have a look into [WPF Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). This is the better approach to use inside of WPF synchronizing UI and data model values. Also have a read of this article about [The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which is probably what you want to try to work towards implementing.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a fallback value declaritively using:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyStringProperty,FallbackValue='Not available'}" />
```

This assumes you are using data binding as you would if you were adopting the MVVM design pattern, which I would recommend for a number of reasons described [here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx).